# Using categorical variable in Conditional Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic, clogit

I have a set of data with lots of events and I want to try and predict the outcome of the event.  I have built a basic conditional logistic regression model but I want to add categorical variables that describe the event.
When I add them in either as binary [1,0]'s or factors they are removed, presumable this is because of the the 'conditional' part of the regression.

Here is a very simple example:

```
library(data.table)
library(mclogit)
dt <- data.table(y = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1),
                 id = c(rep(111, 4), rep(222, 4), rep(333, 4), rep(444, 2)),
                 x1 = rnorm(14),
                 x2 = c(rep("t1", 4), rep("t2", 4), rep("t1", 4), rep("t2", 2)))


mod <- mclogit(cbind(y, id) ~ x1 + x2, data = dt)

summary(mod)
```

In my example`x2` is the categorical variable.

How do I code up the categorical variables so I can use them?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Apologies, Ive edited it now.

Comment: Seems like a pure R usage issue.

Comment: @Björn do you have any suggestions as to how I can add in the categorical variables?

Comment: Read the manual? Switch to PROC LOGISTIC in SAS or StatXact or the rjags (or rstan or rstanarm etc.) R package, if this function does not do it?